# Magento 2.3.1 - URL rewrite rules are not creating for product after update url key

Tags: magento2, products, url-rewrite, url-key

Any one faced below issue in default Magento 2.3.1 and if found any solution then please help us to solve this.

We are facing an issue with URL rewrite rules in fresh Magento 2.3.1 version.

> Issue: URL of the product does not getting updated after change URL
>   key of category in multi-website setup. (NOTE: This issue is not
>   coming when only one website is set up)

```
Precondition:
Fresh Magento 2.3.1
One category which has one product.
Multi website setup.

Steps to reproduce error:
Step 1: Go to the category at admin side.
Step 2: Update URL key of category.
Step 3: Save category.
```

> Actual result: New URL rules are created with updated the key for the
>   category but not created for the product. NOTE: URL rules of the
>   product are created for the second website which does not default
>   website, rules only not created for the mail website product.
>
> Expected result: Rules should be created/updated for the category and
>   all products which are assigned to this category as well it should be
>   created for all websites.